# SOQL. I need some objects that was modified week ago

Tags: apex, soql

Can I get only object, that satisfy something like this
`LastModifiedDate.date().daysBetween(Date.today()) > 7` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can but you must do it in two steps.

```
Datetime lastWeek = datetime.now().addDays(-7);
List<Object__c> theList = [select Id from Object__c where LastModifiedDate >= :lastWeek];
```

Comment: Of course! I'm stupid. Ty!

Answer (score 9):

The value LAST_WEEK is a SOQL reserved phrase, so you can literally do:

```
SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE createdDate = LAST_WEEK
```

and that will return the accounts created last week. It's as simple as that.

Thank you **Derek F** for the valid expansion on this... there are a number of reserved terms (literals) for different date ranges, that can be used with all the logical expressions, such as = as well as < and > which can be found in the [salesforce documentation here.](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.198.0.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm)

Comment: Expanding on this answer a bit, there are [a variety of SOQL Date Literals that can be used](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.198.0.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm). With the example query given in the answer, the `createdDate = <date literal>` translates to "createdDate falls within last week". Similarly, the less than (`<`) and greater than (`>`) operators would translate to "createdDate is before/after (respectively) last week". This behavior can be used with any of the SOQL Date Literals.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it like this :

```
SELECT Id, LastModifiedDate FROM Account WHERE LastModifiedDate < LAST_N_DAYS:7
```